Can MOC7811 slotted opto isolator work with line coded polycarbonate encoder disk?

I want to develop a low cost optical encoder using MOC7811 that measures RPM of a ground wheel. The max RPM is 96, The Pulse/rev required is at least 360, as higher PPR allows for better resolution and accuracy at lower speeds.
I have seen projects where slotted disk is used with MOC7811. However, the encoder disk I am planning to use is a line coded polycarbonate disk (as shown in image). This is similar to the disks used in printers. I want to know whether MOC7811 can easily work with this type of disk.
Also, does it have sufficient response to output the required PPR?

The disk is just for reference.   I am planning to make one myself with atleast 360 lines.


I want to develop a low cost optical encoder using MOC7811 that measures RPM of a ground wheel. The max RPM is 96 ...

Just need a reference ... Measure done on one revolution.
Ton/Toff are 12/60 us for the MOC7811.
So, at a speed of 96 rpm, it could be used ...


I'll update how the sensor behaves once I have the disk.

If you need to measure "angular position" of the disk then this solution can't be used ...
